# How to exclude certain libraries on build vs dev

Tags: gruntjs, environment-variables, build-process

Using Grunt, I have a serve and a build task.

I would like to remove certain lines from my code when the build task is run

```
<!-- don't want from here -->
<script src="../components/jquery-mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/mockjax-mocks.js"></script>
<!-- to here -->
```

But if there is some sort of library that's built around environment variables in Grunt that may solve this problem as well as others in the future...

Answer (score 3):

I use [grunt-preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess) to do that.

In your `build` task, you have to add this task to remove the html you want. The basic sintaxis is like that:

```
    preprocess: {
        options: {
            inline: true,
            context : {
                DEBUG: false
            }
        },
        html : {
            src : [
                'your_path/index.html',
            ]
        }
    }
```

In your index.html, add the conditional named `DEBUG`:

```
<!-- @if DEBUG -->
<script src="../components/jquery-mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/mockjax-mocks.js"></script>
<!-- @endif -->
```